# Understanding the Data from a .csproj-File

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have some Solutions, which are very old and everybody who worked on them is gone.
So far so funny, my first problem: Which VS Version to use.

In the csproj-Files I found this entry (Since you cant see it, its a PropertyGroup followed by VisiualStudioVersion == 10):

10.0

Wouldnt the 10.0 mean, in fact it is Visual Studio 2010? According f.e. to the Installation-Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE, which opens the VS 2010?

Another Property I can't understand is the TargetFrameWorkVersion:

v4.5

This Project was not changed since early 2012, and according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.5 4.5 was first released at 01.07.2012.

Am I doing something horribly wrong? I keep getting the following Error:

> The project type is not supported by this installation.

I have definitely no MVC-Project (which seems to cause troubles and shoot this error), but it's a SharePoint project, could that be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 supports Visual Studio 2010 solution and project files without changing anything in the .sln or .csproj file and also supports Framework version 4.5. Try to open the solution/project in 2012.

Comment: You have to have web project support in Visual Studio. If you didn't install it, you'll have to add it (using the VS installer). Also, if you only have VS Express, it might be tricky to get this working. As for FW 4.5, it would have been available before the official release so your project might have used a pre-release version, or you might be wrong about the project not being changed in the mean-time :)

Comment: But does the 10.0 mean in Fact it is a Visual Studio 2010 Project? Why do I get the Error then? We have VS 2010 Ultimate.